# How do I prevent a const& argument from being changed indirectly?

Tags: c++, reference, immutability, side-effects, c++17

Is it possible to make a `const&` truely immutable?

```
int* side_effect;
void function(int const& i){
  *side_effect = 123;
}

int main(){

  int i = 0;
  side_effect = &i;

  //based on the function signature, i is suspected not to change.  
  //however, that is not the case.
  function(i);
}
```

Are there any compiler warnings, attributes, compiler extensions, or language features I can employ to avoid these kinds of problems?

Comment: Didn't we have this question just recently? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34509616).

Comment: `const &` does not mean "can't be changed". It means "can't be changed **through this argument**".

Comment: Create a local copy instead of a reference to something else!

Comment: (M)any feature(s) can be broken deliberately. Having a global pointer should not be used the way it is used in your example. However you may try to put a check such as `if(side_effect != &i)` before assigning.

Comment: Declare `const int i = 0;` and the compiler will certainly warn you when you assign it's address to a non-const pointer. Any other possible interpretation of your question leads to extensive and somewhat pointless (though pointered) run-time checks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value to be a true constant, you can pass it as a template value argument.

```
template<int i>
void function(){
  *side_effect = 123;
}
```

there is no way for any operation to modify `i`.

This requires that the input be a compile-time constant (and verified so by the compiler at compile time).

So this doesn't work:

```
int main(){
  int i = 0;
  side_effect = &i;

  function<i>();
}
```

as `i` is not a compile-time constant.  If we instead made it:

```
int main(){
  const int i = 0;
  side_effect = &i;

  function<i>();
}
```

the `function<i>` line works, but the `side_effect = &i` doesn't work.  If we add in a cast:

```
int main(){
  const int i = 0;
  side_effect = const_cast<int*>(&i);

  function<i>();
}
```

now the operation `*side_effect = 123` becomes UB within `function`.

Another approach which doesn't require that the value being passed in is a true compile-time constant is to not take a reference:

```
void function(int i){
  *side_effect = 123;
}
```

and instead take a local copy (either `int` or `const int` as the argument, depending on if we want `function` to have the rights to modify `i`).

The full strength version of what you want -- that we take a reference to external data, and then ensure that the external data remains unchanged -- can pretty easily be shown to be equivalent to the halting problem in the general case.